# Is it possible to type a non printable ASCII control character in a DevExpress text editor?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-parsing, devexpress

In our application we have a simple DevExpress text edit field, which is bound to a string property info of a class named ProjectInfo:

```
<ViewBase xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
          ... some more declarations>

    <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding ProjectInfo.ConstructionProjects, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    ...
</ViewBase>
```

The ProjectInfo class:

```
public class ProjectInfo : ModelBase
{
    ...
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ConstructionProjects{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

While working on a project, the ProjectInfo is held in a Session class, and upon calling a save function it gets stored in an object of type Project among some other data, which is then serialized into an XML, zipped and saved on disk.

```
public class Session : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public bool Save(string fileName, bool updateDatabase)
    {
        Project project = new Project()
        {
            ProjectInfo = this.ProjectInfo,
            ...
        }

        using (MemoryStream documentStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Project));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(documentStream, project);
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

There really isn't anything unusual or special to it. Recently, though, a customer complained about not being able to open a certain project and upon examination of the XML file in the zip I stumbled upon this nasty piece of text:

```
<ProjectInfo ConstructionProjects="Wiesenäckerweg 46, Grötzingen&#x13;&#x14;&#x7;&#x13;&#x14;&#x7;"
             ...>
    ...
</ProjectInfo>
```

Now these little hex values translate to the following non-printable ASCII control characters:

- x13 = Device Control 3
- x14 = Device Control 4
- x7 = Bell

As far as I know the bell is supposed to make the receiver beep but the meaning of DC3 and 4 is beyond me. Anyway, trying to XML-decrypt it throws an invalid character exception.

Now, of course, a mean and well versed user could have simply opened the zip, extract and modify the XML manually, but assuming they're not. Is there any chance these control characters could have found their way into the parsed XML file only through our UI? I tried using alt + 7 and alt + 1, alt + 9 and alt + 2, alt + 0 but that actually draws other printable characters. I also tried \a but that doesn't convert to the xml code. Is there a way to get ASCII control characters into a string so they represent their html code after XML parsing?

Comment: You can use windows "Character Map" tool to insert any code into input field (try it). Customer could just pasted something wrong accidentally when they were copying adress.

Comment: and just filter out the non printable characters before saving (google finds plenty of examples so I wont repeat here)

Comment: @Sinatr That's true for printable characters (and those don't let the xml importer crash). It doesn't feature a carriage return, start of heading or synchronous idle, however.

Comment: @Rob The question is not what I have to do about it but rather *whether* I have to do anything about it ;) If there is no possibility other than the customer meddling with the file on purpose in a text editor, I won't do anything about it. Then it's his own fault.